# Deal with the output of `str_locate_all` in tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

*I look for motifs in the sequence of characters. Once I find them I would like to plot a graph with the positions of motifs in the sequence (x - length of the sequence (always 100), y - number of motifs on the given position of the sequence).*

*My idea is to create a table with 100 columns (length of the sequence), that will be filled with e.g "1" on the places of motif position.*

I start with the table, in which I have **ID** of the sequence, and **seq** containing the sequence:

```
table <- tibble(id = c("AT1", "AT2", "AT3"),
                seq = c("AAGCCCATTTAGGGTTTTTTTTAAGCCCAGACCCGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGGGTTTAAGAGAGAGTTTTTTTGAGAGC",
                        "AACTTGGCCCAAAAAAAAGCCCATTTAGGGTTAAAACAGTAGCAAAAAAACGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTTAGGGTTTGAGAGATTTTTTTAA",
                        "GTTTTTTTAGGGTTTAGTTAAAAAAATAGCAGGGTTTAGGACTCTAATTTAGGGTTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGAGATTTTTTTAGGGTAGAGCTAGCA"))
```

Then, I look for declared motifs (**AAAAAAA** and **TTTTTTT** using `str_locate_all` (I want to find the position of all motifs):

```
table2 <- table %>% 
  mutate(AAAAAAA = str_locate_all(seq, "AAAAAAA")) %>%
  mutate(TTTTTTT = str_locate_all(seq, "TTTTTTT"))
```

What gives, unfortunately, only `start` and `end` position of the motif:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  id    seq                                                                                                  AAAAAAA           TTTTTTT          
  <chr> <chr>                                                                                                <list>            <list>           
1 AT1   AAGCCCATTTAGGGTTTTTTTTAAGCCCAGACCCGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGGGTTTAAGAGAGAGTTTTTTTGAGAGC   <int[,2] [0 × 2]> <int[,2] [2 × 2]>
2 AT2   AACTTGGCCCAAAAAAAAGCCCATTTAGGGTTAAAACAGTAGCAAAAAAACGGACTCTAATTGCTCCGTATTCTTTAGGGTTTGAGAGATTTTTTTAA   <int[,2] [2 × 2]> <int[,2] [1 × 2]>
3 AT3   GTTTTTTTAGGGTTTAGTTAAAAAAATAGCAGGGTTTAGGACTCTAATTTAGGGTTATTCTTCTTCTCTTGAGAGAGATTTTTTTAGGGTAGAGCTAGCA <int[,2] [1 × 2]> <int[,2] [2 × 2]>
```

Here I got stuck, as I do not know how to extract values from the motifs columns. I think about creating an output as follow (split motifs column to separate `data.frames` and then filling the positions between `start` and `end`:

```
AAAAAAA <- matrix(nrow = 3, ncol = 100)
row.names(AAAAAAA) <- c("AT1", "AT2", "AT3")
AAAAAAA[2, c(11:17, 44:50)] <- 1
AAAAAAA[3, c(20:26)] <- 1

    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20] [,21] [,22] [,23] [,24] [,25] [,26] [,27] [,28] [,29] [,30] [,31] [,32] [,33]
AT1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    [,34] [,35] [,36] [,37] [,38] [,39] [,40] [,41] [,42] [,43] [,44] [,45] [,46] [,47] [,48] [,49] [,50] [,51] [,52] [,53] [,54] [,55] [,56] [,57] [,58] [,59] [,60] [,61] [,62] [,63] [,64] [,65]
AT1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1     1     1     1     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    [,66] [,67] [,68] [,69] [,70] [,71] [,72] [,73] [,74] [,75] [,76] [,77] [,78] [,79] [,80] [,81] [,82] [,83] [,84] [,85] [,86] [,87] [,88] [,89] [,90] [,91] [,92] [,93] [,94] [,95] [,96] [,97]
AT1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
AT3    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    [,98] [,99] [,100]
AT1    NA    NA     NA
AT2    NA    NA     NA
AT3    NA    NA     NA
```

Then I think to join back all tables into one big and make a plot using `ggplot`.

I describe the whole problem as I am not sure if I approach it in a good way and would appreciate any hints on how to "extract" / "simplify" output of `str_locate_all` or general tips.

**EDIT**
My expected final output is the table that let me plot the positions of all motifs over the sequence length (to see whether motifs distribute e.g. at the beginning of sequence).

Comment: What is your final expected output? Two matrix (`AAAAAAA` and  `TTTTTTT`) with 1's and `NA`s filled?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

you can write one function (I called it `make_vec`) which takes the sequence and a pattern as input and returns the row of the matrix.

```
make_vec <- function(seq, pattern) {
  loc <- str_locate_all(seq, pattern)[[1]]
  res <- integer(100)
  idx <- as.numeric(sapply(loc[,1], function(x) x + seq_len(nchar(pattern)) - 1))
  res[idx] <- 1L
  return(res)
}
```

Next you can use this function for every sequence and exract the results:

```
table3 <- table %>% 
  mutate(
    a = map(seq, make_vec, pattern = "AAAAAAA"),
    t = map(seq, make_vec, pattern = "TTTTTTT"),
  )

  matrix(unlist(table3$a), nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: It's a solution close to what I wanted to get :D But when looking at output of `matrix(unlist(table3$a), nrow = 3)` it's visible that something is wrong... The motifs are disrupted here. Is it a fault of `nrow`?

Comment: Yes, but I mean when you look at the final output, there is e.g motif with length 2, what shouldn't happen